# Find an iOS bundle identifier in the flutter application

Tags: ios, flutter, bundle-identifier, flutter-ios

I am working on a flutter app and cannot find the bundle identifier.  According to the documentation here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup), it should be in the General tab but I can't find it.  I've also read in places that it could be here: ios/Runner.xcodeproj but my project doesn't contain that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Easiest way to find it is doing the following:

- Open your Flutter Project on **Android Studio** or **VS Code**
- Search `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER =`
- Hit Enter, open the file and check your `Bundle Identifier`

[image: Android Studio Search]

There's other way to do it but you need **MacOS** with **XCode** installed:

- With **Finder** got to your Flutter folder, then iOS and open `Runner.xcworkspace` (white icon)
- Double click and open it on XCode.
- Upper left corner (Project Navigation), click on `Runner`
- Over **Identity** you'll have several fields, one of those is `Bundle Identifier`

[image: XCode Project Navigation]

Comment: Thanks @Mariano Zorrilla!

Answer (score 3):

For Bundle ID and Package Name changes,

For IOS:

1. Look for file

> project/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/Info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>

<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>notification</string>
```

2. To change the value, look for file

> project/ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

```
PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER = com.sara.fcm.notification;
```

3. flutter clean

For Android (4 places):

1. AndroidManifest.xml

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
> android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
> android/app/src/profile/AndroidManifest.xml

2. android/app/build.gradle

   ```
   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.sara.fcm.notification"
    ....
   }
   ```
3. (kotlin or java)
   android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/../MainActivity.kt

```
package com.sara.fcm.notification
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {}
```

4. Refactor the directory name(MainActivity) and flutter clean

Answer (score 0):

### Here is the simplest way:

It's the value inside the `String` tag in file `Info.plist` located in the folder `ios/Runner` .

[image]

**Bundle ID** will be  here : `<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>`

[image]

> You can modify it